# Asymptotic expansion involving hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

For $n\in\mathbb Z$, define $p_n$ as
$$p_n =  e^{-2\pi \eta|n|} \begin{cases}
   \binom{-\alpha}{n} \: _2{F}{_1}(-\alpha, n+\alpha; n+1; e^{-4\pi \eta}), & n\geq 0, \\
   \binom{\alpha}{-n} \: _2{F}{_1}(-n-\alpha, \alpha; 1-n; e^{-4\pi \eta}), & n\leq 0.
  \end{cases},$$
where $\eta>0$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ are constants, $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function, and $\binom{\cdot}{\cdot}$ is the (generalized) binomial coefficients.

> Question: What is the asymptotic behavior of $|p_n|^2$, for each
> $n\to\infty$ and $n\to-\infty$?

Remarks:

1. I tried some numerical experiments. For $\eta=0.02$ and $\alpha=1.5$, the log-plot of $|p_n|^2$ is,

[image]

I think that $|p_n|^2$ decays as $\sim n^a e^{-b n}$ for some constants $a,b>0$, different for $n\to\infty$ and $n\to-\infty$.

2. I know that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} |p_n|^2=1$, because it comes from a certain probability distribution.

Comment: Does $$
p_n^2  \sim \frac{{(1 - {\rm e}^{ - 4\pi \eta } )^{ \pm 2\alpha } }}{{\Gamma ^2 ( \pm \alpha )}}\left| n \right|^{ \pm 2\alpha  - 2} {\rm e}^{ - 4\pi \eta \left| n \right|} 
$$ as $n\to \pm\infty$ work?

Comment: @Gary Yes it works! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I checked the last steps from my calculation and you indeed get what @Gary suggested when including the approximation of the quotient of the Gamma functions suggested by the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For brevity, I've denoted ${}_2F_1$ simply as $F$.

It is simple to see that

$$F(a,b;c;z) \sim 1 +\frac{ab}{c}z$$

as $|c|\rightarrow \infty$. Then, using a relationship of the hypergeometric function gives for the first relation

$$F(-\alpha,n+\alpha;n+1;v) = (1-v)^{\alpha}F\left(-\alpha,1-\alpha;n+1;\frac{v}{v-1}\right) \sim (1-v)^{\alpha}\left(1+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{n+1}\frac{v}{v-1} \right)$$

where $v = \exp(-4\pi\eta)$. For the second, I changed $-n\rightarrow n$, then the function of interest is

$$F(n-\alpha;\alpha;1+n,v) = (1-v)^{-\alpha}  F\left(1+\alpha,\alpha;1-n;\frac{v}{v-1}\right) \sim (1-v)^{-\alpha} \left(1+\frac{\alpha(1+\alpha)}{1+n}\frac{v}{v-1} \right)$$

Note that normally, the convergence depends on if $\left|\left( \frac{v}{v-1}\right)\right| <1$ or not. In this case, this is true for all values of $v$ except when $v=1$, occuring at $\eta=0$. Close to this point, convergence is slower.

An example of the first approximation is given in the figure below.[image]

For the binomial coefficients, you can write these in terms of Gamma functions, using the asymptotic expression for these and then piecing things together should give you the asymptotic expression for the whole.

For the first part, note that $$\binom{-\alpha}{n} = (-1)^n\binom{n+a-1}{n}=(-1)^n \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+n)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\alpha)}$$

then,

$$ p_n^2 \sim e^{-4\pi\eta n} \left(\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+n)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\alpha)} \right)^2 \left(1-e^{-4\pi\eta}\right)^{2\alpha} \sim e^{-4\pi\eta n} \left(\frac{(n+\alpha)^{n+\alpha-1/2}e^{1-\alpha}}{(n+1)^{n+1/2}\Gamma(\alpha)} \right)^2 \left(1-e^{-4\pi\eta}\right)^{2\alpha}$$

where I've only kept the first term of the hypergeometric function and used that $\Gamma(z) \sim \sqrt{2\pi}z^{z-1/2}e^{-z}$.

Small comment: the legend in the figure is wrong wrt the parameters in F, should be the first hypergeometric function without modifications.

Comment: You can use $\Gamma(\alpha+n)/\Gamma(n+1) \sim n^{\alpha-1}$ to simplify your result (see [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11#iii)).

Comment: MathJax tip: use \exp, \sin, \lim etc. to produce the appropriate looking $\exp$, $\sin$, $\lim$ etc. insted of the odd looking $exp$, $sin$, $lim$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your result nicely fits with the exact value, as I tested with Mathematica.

Comment: @Gary, sorry for the formating! I saw you edited most of my posts, I'll try to do better! :)